# Prooftree with nodes below other nodes

Tags: logic

I require large prooftrees using the `bussproofs`, but the layouting seems to be not optimal. In particular, the package does not place nodes of the tree below other nodes, which would save a lot of horizontal space. E.g. in the image below, I would like to have the circled node further to the left, such that it is approximately below the node labeled `Z(d)`. However in the `bussproofs` documentation, I cannot find any option that would allow to do so. Is there some way this can be done?

[image]
MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{bussproofs}

\newcommand{\AxiomCm}[1]{\AxiomC{$#1$}}
\newcommand{\BinaryInfCm}[1]{\BinaryInfC{$#1$}}
\newcommand{\UnaryInfCm}[1]{\UnaryInfC{$#1$}}

\begin{document}
\begin{prooftree}

  \AxiomCm{ G(x, y) \lor L(x, y) \lor x = y }
  \AxiomCm{ \lnot Z(z) \lor \lnot  L(z, u) }
  \BinaryInfCm{  G(x, y) \lor x=y \lor \lnot Z(x) }

  \AxiomCm{ \lnot Z(w) \lor \lnot Z(f(w)) }
  \AxiomCm{ Z(d)}
  \BinaryInfCm{ \lnot Z(f(d)) }

  \BinaryInfCm{ G(x, f(d)) \lor \lnot Z(x) \lor \lnot Z(x) }
  \UnaryInfCm{ G(x, f(d)) \lor \lnot Z(x)  }

  \AxiomCm{ \lnot G(v, f(v)) }

  \BinaryInfCm{  \lnot Z(d)  }

  \AxiomCm{ Z(d) }

  \BinaryInfCm{  \bot }
\end{prooftree}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\insertBetweenHyps` to insert negative space between the hypotheses for that particular inference. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{bussproofs}

\newcommand{\AxiomCm}[1]{\AxiomC{$#1$}}
\newcommand{\BinaryInfCm}[1]{\BinaryInfC{$#1$}}
\newcommand{\UnaryInfCm}[1]{\UnaryInfC{$#1$}}

\begin{document}
\begin{prooftree}

  \AxiomCm{ G(x, y) \lor L(x, y) \lor x = y }
  \AxiomCm{ \lnot Z(z) \lor \lnot  L(z, u) }
  \BinaryInfCm{  G(x, y) \lor x=y \lor \lnot Z(x) }

  \AxiomCm{ \lnot Z(w) \lor \lnot Z(f(w)) }
  \AxiomCm{ Z(d)}
  \BinaryInfCm{ \lnot Z(f(d)) }

  \BinaryInfCm{ G(x, f(d)) \lor \lnot Z(x) \lor \lnot Z(x) }
  \UnaryInfCm{ G(x, f(d)) \lor \lnot Z(x)  }

  \AxiomCm{ \lnot G(v, f(v)) }

  \insertBetweenHyps{\hskip -50pt}

  \BinaryInfCm{  \lnot Z(d)  }

  \AxiomCm{ Z(d) }

  \BinaryInfCm{  \bot }
\end{prooftree}

\end{document}
```

will produce:

[image: Adjusted proof]

See page 12 of [this guide](http://www.logicmatters.net/resources/pdfs/latex/BussGuide2.pdf).